# What's the principle inside ext?

Tags: extjs

I've never used ext myself,

but I see there are many .java files in it.

The strange thing is that it's taken as javascript?

Why?

Comment: It might be helpful if you added a link to your question so the rest of us know what the heck you're talking about.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean ext js by Ext there are **no** Java files in Ext Js itself. Only js files which are javascript.

Maybe you downloaded Ext GWT which is **a Java library** for building rich internet applications with [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/).

Comment: That's right, there are **no** .java files in the Ext JS download.